# Ember-Data Working With JSON-API

Tags: json, express, ember.js, models

I'm trying to link **Ember-Data** with a **JSON-API** backed by **Express.JS**.

---

I know these ...

`models` `adapters` `serializers`

... but how do they **work together**? And how do they fit into the whole picture of **Ember.JS**?

---

How can I set a **secure connection** between JSON-API and Ember.JS?

Comment: Have you worked through the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/)? A secure connection can be established with `HTTPS`. If you want authentication there are many options including but not only limited to `ember-simple-auth`. Generally `model`s are about what kind of data your have, `adapter`s where to find the data, and `serializer`s how they are formatted/serialized.

Comment: I've read most of the guides. I appreciate your comment (Lux) but I'd like to have an answer (much more detailed)... Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you will get one. The question is just too broad. If you want to know ember internals read the code, and if you have problems using it try to be specific, show some code and describe the problems you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extremely broad question but having recently gone through all of this I believe i can provide a detailed response for how **I have implemented** it. This is key because there is a very large amount of options, and if you look up most of the tutorials, they mostly focus around using `rails` as the back end instead of `node` or `express.js`. I will be answering this question based on you using `express.js`.

I'll preface this with remembering that `ember-data` is a completely different offshoot of ember that you can bypass and entirely not use if you feel your project is not going to need the features with it and just use AJAX requests instead. `ember-data` adds a lot of complexity and overhead to the initial start of the project. Additionally **TLS/SSL is the most important security you can have and without it, any amount of attempted security outside of this is invalid without it**. Now that that's out of the way, lets get to the gritty part of setting it up.

By default `ember-data` uses the `JSONAPIAdapter` which is based on the [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/). Your `Express.js` API server is going to have to be able to function to this specification if you use the default `Adapter` with no `Serializer` changes

Breaking the project out into the core components and what they need to do, and the options available is the following (with what I did in bold):

- Express.js API server

  - Express API routes
  - Authentication library

    - **Passport is works well for `express.js`**
    - Custom
  - Authentication mechanism

    - **Token Based**
    - Cookie Based
  - Data Modeling

    - Mongo
    - **Sequelize**
    - Other
- Ember.js based Web Server

  - Adapter (this deals with sending/receiving data and handling errors)

    - application.js: configure an adapter for the whole application
  - Serializer (this deals with making the data from the adapter ember useable)

    - None required by default
  - Authenticator (this

    - `ember-simple-auth` works well
    - Build your own: [example](https://auth0.com/blog/create-your-first-ember-2-dot-0-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api/)
  - Authorizer

    - `ember-simple-auth-token` gives you a prebuilt authorizer using token based authentication
- Database

  - MongoDB (doc-based non-relational database)
  - Redis (in memory non-relational database)
  - **MySQL** (relational database)
  - PostGreSQL (relational database)
  - Other

The basic flow is as follows:

- User attempts to log in on ember.js app
- Ember.js uses authenticator to request access from API server
- API server validates user and returns JSON web token in header
- Ember.js uses authorizer and adds JSON web token to header for future API requests
- API call is made to the API server from Ember through the Adapter with authorizer header
- API server validates token and searches for data required
- API server responds with data in JSON API specification format
- Ember.js adapter receives data and handles response
- Ember.js serializer receives data from adapter and makes it useable by Ember
- Ember data receives model data from serializer and stores it in cache
- Model data is populated based on templates and controllers on Ember.js pages

Here's how i set it up

** Setting `Ember.js` up to use `Express.js` API Server **

Install the following items for ember-cli:

`ember install ember-simple-auth` - For authentication
`ember install ember-simple-auth-token` - For token-based authentication

in `app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin'; // Authenticating data from the API server
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin,{

  authManager: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  host: ENV.apihost, // location of the API server
  namespace: ENV.apinamespace, // Namespace of API server ie: 'api/v1'
  authorizer: 'authorizer:token', // Authorizer to use for authentication

  ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
    hash = hash || {}; // hash may be undefined
    hash.crossDomain = true; // Needed for CORS
    return this._super(url, method, hash);
  }
});
```

In `config/environment.js`:

```
ENV.host = 'http://localhost:4000'; /* this assumes the express.js server
is running on port 4000 locally, in a production environment it would point
to https://domainname.com/ */
ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
   authorizer: 'authorizer:token', //uses ember-simple-auth-token authorizer
   crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://localhost:4000'], // for CORS
   baseURL: '/',
   authenticationRoute: 'login', // Ember.js route that does authentication
   routeAfterAuthentication: 'profile', // Ember.js route to transition to after authentication
   routeIfAlreadyAuthenticated: 'profile' // Ember.js route to transition to if already authenticated
 };

 ENV['ember-simple-auth-token'] = {
   serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:4000/auth/token', // Where to get JWT from
   identificationField: 'email', // identification field that is sent to Express.js server
   passwordField: 'password', // password field sent to Express.js server
   tokenPropertyName: 'token', // expected response key from Express.js server
   authorizationPrefix: 'Bearer ', // header value prefix
   authorizationHeaderName: 'Authorization', // header key
   headers: {},
 };
 ENV['apihost'] = "http://localhost:4000" // Host of the API server passed to `app/adapters/application.js`
 ENV['apinamespace'] = ""; // Namespace of API server passed to `app/adapters/application.js`
```

** Setting up `Express.js` Server **

Required packages:

`express` : Self explanatory
`body-parser` : for parsing JSON from `ember.js` site
`cors` : for CORS support
`ejwt` : for requiring JWT on most routes to your API server
`passport` : for authenticating users
`passport-json` : for authenticating users
`bcrypt` : for hashing/salting user passwords
`sequelize` : for data modeling

** Setting up `server.js` **

```
var express = require('express'); // App is built on express framework
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // For parsing JSON passed to use through the front end app
var cors = require('cors'); // For CORS support
var ejwt = require('express-jwt');
var passport = require('passport');
// Load Configuration files
var Config = require('./config/environment'),
     config = new Config // Load our Environment configuration based on NODE_ENV environmental variable. Default is test.
var corsOptions = {
  origin: config.cors
};    
var app = express(); // Define our app object using express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // use x-www-form-urlencoded used for processing submitted forms from the front end app
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse json bodies that come in from the front end app
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // THIS ALLOWS ACCEPTING EMBER DATA BECAUSE JSON API FORMAT
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // Cross-Origin Resource Sharing support
app.use(passport.initialize()); // initialize passport
app.use(ejwt({ secret: config.secret}).unless({path: ['/auth/token',  { url : '/users', methods: ['POST']}]}));
require('./app/routes')(app); // Load our routes file that handles all the API call routing
app.listen(config.port); // Start our server on the configured port. Default is 4000
console.log('listening on port : ' + config.port);
```

in `config/passport.js`

```
// config/passport.js
// Configure Passport for local logins

// Required Modules
var JsonStrategy = require('passport-json').Strategy;

// 
var User = require('../app/models/users'); // load user model

// Function
module.exports = function (passport) {
// serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id).then(function (user) {
        done(null, user);
    });
});
// LOCAL LOGIN ==========================================================
passport.use('json', new JsonStrategy({
    usernameProp : 'email',
    passwordProp : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function (req, email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({where : {'email' : email }}).then(function (user) { // check against email
        if (!user) {
          User.findOne({where : {'displayName' : email}}).then(function(user){ //check against displayName
          if (!user) return done(null, false);
          else if (User.validatePassword(password,user.password)) return done(null, user);
          else return done(null, false);
          });
        }
        else if (User.validatePassword(password,user.password)) return done(null, user);
        else return done(null, false);
    });
}));
};
```

Example `app/models/users.js` user sequelize model

```
// Load required Packages
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-node')
// Load required helpers
var sequelize = require('../helpers/sequelizeconnect');
var config =  new require('../../config/environment'); // Load our Environment  configuration based on NODE_ENV environmental variable. Default is test.

// Load other models

// Define model
var Users = sequelize.define('users', {
  "email": { type: Sequelize.STRING}, // user email
  "password": { type: Sequelize.STRING} // user password
});

// Methods =======================================================

// Hash a password before storing
Users.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// Compare a password from the DB
Users.validatePassword = function(password, dbpassword) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, dbpassword);
}

module.exports = Users
```

At this point your `express.js` server will just need your `routes.js` set up with routes for what your API server needs, at a minimum of `/auth/token` in order to perform the authentication. An example of a successful response the `Ember.js` JSON API adapter expects is:

```
var jsonObject = { // create json response object
   "data": {
       "type": "users", // ember.js model
       "id": 1, // id of the model
       "attributes": {
           "email" : "example@example.com",
       }
   }
}
res.status(201).json(jsonObject); // send new data object with 201/OK as a response
```

There is a lot more complexities to setting up the JSON API server to respond to Delete requests, Validation errors, etc.